# Skewed variable - better log10 or ln?

Tags: skewness

I am building a logistic regression model and one of my independent variable sis heavily skewed. Is it better to use the ln or the log10? Why?

And how to correct the skewness of a variable that contains a lot of zero values?

Comment: Since changing the base of the logarithm only multiplies by a constant, it changes the scale, not the shape -- so it makes no difference at all which you choose. If you have a high proportion of values at some single value, you can't separate them by a transformation, so generally you can't do much.

Comment: Why would you want to change the skewness of an IV?

Comment: Isn't it better that all the variables are as normal as possible?

Comment: The logarithm of zero is indeterminate in any case.

Comment: This is two questions.  I closed the first one as a duplicate.  The second one is answered in many threads which can be found by searching our site for keywords [zero+skew+regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=zero+skew+regression).

Comment: Better for what reason? Logistic regression doesn't need the IVs to have a normal distribution. Indeed frequently they're binary.